# Why d3 updates entire data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an svg element with data created this way:

```
var chart = d3.select("#my-div").append("svg");
var chartData = [];
chartData.push([{x: 1, y: 3}, {x: 2, y: 5}]);
chartData.push([{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 3}]);

          .domain([1, 5]);
var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
        return xRange(d.x);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return yRange(d.y);
    })
    .interpolate('linear');

chart.append('g').classed('lines', true).selectAll('path').data(chartData).enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
        return lineFunc(d);
    })
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr('fill', 'none');
```

After that I am trying to update my data and update the chart:

```
chartData[1].push({x: 5, y: 5});
chart.selectAll('g.lines').selectAll('path').data(chartData)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
        console.log('updating:');
        console.log(d);
        return lineFunc(d);
    })
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr('fill', 'none');
```

but it prints '**updating**' twice (for both of the chartData elements), but I've changed only one (`chartData[1]`). How to prevent it to not update the ones that I didn't change? I will have many functions, so it will be ineffiecient to update all of them when only one has changed.

// EDIT to @mef's answer

I changed data to (I don't mind updating entire chartData[X] data, I just want to avoid updating entire chartData):

```
chartData.push({key: 'A', data: [{x: 1, y: 3}, {x: 2, y: 5}]});
chartData.push({key: 'B', data: [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 3}]});
```

and then when adding data I've put `.data(chartData, function(d) {return d.key})` and when updating I did the same, but it still updates both.

I tried also to put `.data(chartData, function(d) {return 'A'})` or `.data(chartData, function(d) {return 'B'})` when updating the data and it updates only one, but always the data with `A` key (whether this function returns `A` or `B`).

So the whole code looks like this:

```
var chart = d3.select("#my-div").append("svg");
var chartData = [];
chartData.push({key: 'A', data: [{x: 1, y: 3}, {x: 2, y: 5}]});
chartData.push({key: 'B', data: [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 3}]});

var xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([50, 780]).domain([1, 5]);
var yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([380, 20]).domain([2, 9]);

var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
        return xRange(d.x);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return yRange(d.y);
    })
    .interpolate('linear');

chart.append('g').classed('lines', true).selectAll('path')
    .data(chartData, function(d) {return d.key}).enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
        return lineFunc(d.data);
    })
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr('fill', 'none');
```

updating data

```
chartData[1].data.push({x: 5, y: 5});
chart.selectAll('g.lines').selectAll('path')
    .data(chartData, function(d) {return d.key})
    .attr('d', function(d) {
        console.log('updating:');
        console.log(d);
        return lineFunc(d.data);
    })
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr('fill', 'none');
```

Comment: Well done for posting the revised code :) ...but, it would make it even better if you posted xRange and yRange

Comment: The behaviour is by design, the "update nodes" will be refreshed, the path elements are not deleted and replaced. Adding the key function doesn't change anything in this case because there are the same number of elements in the selections. You need to construct a more elaborate key that is a composite of the data members as suggested by @mef. *BUT* it will still not change the behaviour because the node `datum` is only a reference to the data array element so the keys will match whatever you do.

Comment: You have to jump through a few flaming hoops but it can be done by using the `d3.svg.line()` function in the key and detecting if the key is called on the data or the node (if its the data, use the line function, otherwise use `d3.select(this).attr("d")`).  You also have to align the number formatting in the array with the node `d` attribute text and you can't use the default `Array.prototype.toString` on the value returned by the line function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it can be done...

## Option 1 - use key

Here is a lazy way to do it...

### Strategy

1. Make a key function that will detect changes in data.
   Do this by reading the node attribute string and comparing it with the attribute generator function result, called on the datum.
2. Detect the phase of the d3 data binding process (key on nodes or key on data) and use different key for each:
   `var k = Array.isArray(this) ? lineD(d, lineFunc) : d3.select(this).attr("d");`
3. Align the formatting of the two key values by writing and reading back from a dummy node during the "data key" phase. (that's the lazy part!)
4. Keep separate references for the update, exit and enter selections to decouple their behaviour.

### Code

```
var chart = d3.select("#my-div").append("svg")
      .attr("height", 600)
      .attr("width", 900);
var chartData = [];
chartData.push([{x: 1, y: 3}, {x: 2, y: 5}]);
chartData.push([{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 3}]);

var xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([50, 780]).domain([1, 5]);
var yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([380, 20]).domain([2, 9]);

var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
      return xRange(d.x);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
      return yRange(d.y);
    })
    .interpolate('linear');

chart.append('g').classed('lines', true).selectAll('path')
    .data(chartData, key)
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return lineFunc(d);
    })
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr('fill', 'none');
//updating data

chartData[1].push({x: 5, y: 5});

var update = chart.selectAll('g.lines').selectAll('path')
      .data(chartData, key);
update.enter().append('path')
      .attr('d', function (d) {
        console.log('updating:');
        console.log(d);
        return lineFunc(d);
      })
      .attr('stroke', 'black')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1)
      .attr('fill', 'none');
update.exit().remove();

function key(d, i, j) {
  var k = Array.isArray(this) ? lineAttr(d, lineFunc, "d") : d3.select(this).attr("d");
  console.log((Array.isArray(this) ? "data\t" : "node\t") + k)
  return k;

  function lineAttr(d, lineFunct, attribute) {
    var l = d3.select("svg").selectAll("g")
      .append("path").style("display", "none")
      .attr(attribute, lineFunct(d))
    d = l.attr(attribute);
    l.remove();
    return d;
  }
}
```

Output

```
node    M50,328.57142857142856L232.5,225.71428571428572          
node    M50,380L232.5,328.57142857142856                         
data    M50,328.57142857142856L232.5,225.71428571428572          
data    M50,380L232.5,328.57142857142856L780,225.71428571428572

updating:                                                      
Array[3]0: Object1: Object2: Objectlength: 3__proto__: Array[0]
```

## Option 2 - use filter

This is more efficient but only applies if you know that only the number of points on the lines will change and the number of lines is fixed.

### Strategy

1. Join the data without a *key* function and filter it by comparing
   the attribute string calculated from the bound data, to the current attribute string in the DOM element.
2. As in option 1, use a dummy node as a lazy (and cross-browser) way to align the formatting of the node attribute and the calculated attribute text.

### Code

```
//updating data

chartData[1].push({x: 5, y: 5});

chart.selectAll('g.lines').selectAll('path')
  .data(chartData)
  .filter(changed)
  .attr('d', function (d) {
    console.log('updating:');
    console.log(d);
    return lineFunc(d);
  })
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1)
  .attr('fill', 'none');

function changed(d) {
  var s = d3.select(this);
  console.log("data\t" + lineAttr(s.datum(), lineFunc, "d"));
  console.log("node\t" + s.attr("d")); console.log("\n")
  return lineAttr(s.datum(), lineFunc, "d") != s.attr("d");

  function lineAttr(d, lineFunct, attribute) {
    var l = d3.select("svg").selectAll("g")
      .append("path").style("display", "none")
      .attr(attribute, lineFunct(d))
    d = l.attr(attribute);
    l.remove();
    return d;
  }
}
```

Output

```
data    M50,328.57142857142856L232.5,225.71428571428572
node    M50,328.57142857142856L232.5,225.71428571428572

data    M50,380L232.5,328.57142857142856L780,225.71428571428572
node    M50,380L232.5,328.57142857142856

updating:
Array[3]
```

## Option 3 - best of both worlds

### Strategy

1. Use a standard update/enter/exit pattern.
2. Filter the update selection to form a "changed" selection before operating on it.

## Code

```
//updating data

alert("base");
chartData[1].push({ x: 5, y: 5 });
updateViz();
alert("change");
chartData.push([{x: 3, y: 1}, {x: 5, y: 2}])
updateViz();
alert("enter");
chartData.shift();
updateViz();
alert("exit");

function updateViz() {
  var update = chart.selectAll('g.lines').selectAll('path')
      .data(chartData),

      enter = update.enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', function (d) {
          return lineFunc(d);
        })
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
        .attr('fill', 'none'),

      changed = update.filter(changed)
        .attr('d', function (d) {
          console.log('updating:');
          console.log(d);
          return lineFunc(d);
        });

  update.exit().remove();

  function changed(d) {
    var s = d3.select(this);
    console.log("data\t" + lineAttr(s.datum(), lineFunc, "d"));
    console.log("node\t" + s.attr("d")); console.log("\n")
    return lineAttr(s.datum(), lineFunc, "d") != s.attr("d");

    function lineAttr(d, lineFunct, attribute) {
      var l = d3.select("svg").selectAll("g")
        .append("path").style("display", "none")
        .attr(attribute, lineFunct(d))
      d = l.attr(attribute);
      l.remove();
      return d;
    }
  }
}
```

## Background

Read [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [key function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data), in order to allow to d3 to find out whether the records have changed, and match accordingly when you update the dataset.

At the moment, your data elements are *javascript objects*, and d3 does not check whether they have been changed compared to previous version (that would be tricky).

Ideally, you should find a unique identifier for your records, and include it in your dataset.

You would then replace `.data(chartData)`

by `.data(chartData, function(d) { return d.id })`

In case you have no property in your dataset you could use as unique record identifier, you still can do something like this:

```
.data(chartData, function(d) {
    return d.map(function(coord) {
        return coord.x + '-' + coord.y
    }).join('-')
}
```

The key here would be a concatenation of all coordinates values of your object.

Comment: Could you please check the edited stuff in my question? Thanks.

Comment: actually there is a small typo in your second key function: you need to replace `return d.x + '-' + d.y` with `return coord.x + '-' + coord.y`

Comment: It still doesn't work though... I forgot how complicated this was