# d3.js enter() update() exit() pattern, but with custom comparison of key value pairs

Tags: object, design-patterns, d3.js

Is there some way of coercing the d3.js enter/update/exit (EUE) pattern to allow comparison -in addition to primitive data types- of arbitrary key / value pairs? If so, how?

I have in mind the comparison of objects, as in current values such as {part:0,duration:2} vs previous values {part:0,duration:0}, expressed in a possible comparison function as d.duration, d.part, d.whatever).

To give you an idea what I'm after, imagining the arrays to be vertical selections in a time-based sequence, a typical scenario might (at time divisions 10 and 12) be:

```
    ----[10]-- sampling interval=2 --[12]-----
         :                            :
      prev_array                  curr_array
         :                            :
         :  /other data               :  /other data undefined
part:   [0] -duration 6 -----------> [0] -duration undefined, as overlap from prev
         :  \     :                   :  \    :
         :                            :
         :  /other data undefined     :  /other data
part:   [1] -duration undefined      [1] -duration 2 (new)
         :  \     :                   :  \    :
         :                            :
         :  /other data               :  /other data undefined
part:   [2] -duration 4 -----------> [2] -duration undefined, as overlap from prev
         :  \     :                   :  \    :
         :                            :
         :  /other data               :  /other data  
part:   [3] -duration 2              [3] -duration 4 (new) 
            \     :                      \    :
```

Previous attempts using field-by-field comparison in nested selection.each() calls (the selections having been made on prev_array and curr_array) were hamstrung by problems with returned value scope and/or asynchronous behaviour. Hence my interest in direct application of the EUE pattern. A couple of conclusions:

- I can only act on DOM once differences in prev and curr arrays have been found.
- implies that the comparison I had thought to do directly as part of EUE is best done using built-in or d3 array methods in a comparator function.
- the issue of how to compare apply the **results** to the DOM are probably answered by the key or other approaches mentioned below.

Tricky situation in a tricky language, but results from a desire to handle time-sequenced, chained transitions on freely pluggable and highly configurable SPA animations in a very flexible and reusable way.

Nevertheless, any examples illustrating similar / relevant situations remain more than welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand your question, but I think you want to compare (and possibly filter) two arrays and give the result to D3? Because I do know that the data function of D3 can contain another function and you will be ok as long as it returns an array of something. I am thinking something like this:  `selectAll( element ).data( function(array1, array2){ /* do your comparing*/ return customarray; } ).enter().append('rect')`

Comment: Looks promising. Maybe I've been too focussed on the workings of the original enter/update/exit pattern..

Comment: Might be an idea to edit your question to make it comprehensible.

Comment: D3 doesn't store the previous data so you'd have to do that yourself. See [pie chart transitions](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) for an example.

Comment: Ok, it's a little bit clearer. I think you are talking about binding data. You can enhance that by providing a `key` function as suggested by @Ian. They can be tricky though, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30897809/2670182) is an example of updating based on element type and node colour. You can generalise that to update based on properties inside the data like I think you want, but you have to splice the changed data elements into the data array so that the datum on the element and the data element are not referencing the same object.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30626338/2670182) is another example.

Comment: If this answer helped please feel free to accept it, if not could you clarify what problems you are still facing?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do this is to use the `data()` key function. If you read the [API Docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) you'll see the 2nd parameter.

```
selection.data([values[, key]])
```

Essentially you can provide a function to generate the key on your data, which could return just an ID, or generate a hash of particular fields you're interested in. An example of calling it would be:

```
selection.data(myData, function(d) { 
    return d.myCustomKey;
});
```